# Problem to Scrape and bypass sucuri protection

Tags: javascript, cookies, web-scraping, header, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape the `https://twist.moe/` page, but cheerio doesn't show me the content of the page. Apparently it uses some sucuri protection.

When using cheerio it shows me:

```html
<html><head><title>You are being redirected...</title>
<noscript>Javascript is required. Please enable javascript before you are allowed to see this page.</noscript>
<script>var s={},u,c,U,r,i,l=0,a,e=eval,w=String.fromCharCode,sucuri_cloudproxy_js='',S='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';L=S.length;U=0;r='';var A='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';for(u=0;u<64;u++){s[A.charAt(u)]=u;}for(i=0;i<L;i++){c=s[S.charAt(i)];U=(U<<6)+c;l+=6;while(l>=8){((a=(U>>>(l-=8))&0xff)||(i<(L-2)))&&(r+=w(a));}}e(r);</script></head><body>
</body></html>
```

From chrome I accessed dev-tools and found two cookie values

```js
"sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_645833be2=0fa8e64535001a7393d98096a1bf40a5" 
"sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_f735b3372=77a9f80992e5d2cc9ffda8e165f8dcfb"
```

Both values I pass them to the header, but still shows me the same output.

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const url = require('./urls');
const util = require('../utils');


const animeList = async() =>{
  const headers = {
    cookie: "sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_645833be2=0fa8e64535001a7393d98096a1bf40a5; sucuri_cloudproxy_uuid_f735b3372=77a9f80992e5d2cc9ffda8e165f8dcfb;"
  }
  const {data} = await axios.get('https://twist.moe/' , {headers});
  const body = await data;
  const $ = cheerio.load(body);
  const promises = [];

  console.log($.html());
};

animeList();
```

Can someone show me how to get all the HTML content of the page `https://twist.moe/`?

Comment: Try using something like Selenium (works with JavaScript-only pages) to load the content, then process it. I had a similar issue with a similar project, and while slower, that was the best workaround I could find. Or, try PhantomJS to render the JS, then scrape it with Cheerio.

Comment: I would provide an example, but I'm currently at work. If no one else provides an example, I will when I get home.

Comment: Hi @Ellis Any example that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved using the npm package [cloudscraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudscraper) which is Node.js library to bypass Cloudflare's anti-DDOS page. Cloudscraper can also identify and automatically bypass Sucuri.

```js
const animeList = async() =>{
  const res = await cloudscraper.get(`${url.BASE_URL}`);
  const body = await res;
  const $ = cheerio.load(body);
  const promises = [];

  console.log($.html());
};
```

Comment: Cloudscraper is deprecated, cos it doesn't work anymore.